# MVC (Razor) Syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In my razor view i have below code :

```
@foreach (var rma in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @{
            if (rma.AntalRMA == rma.Antal.Remove(rma.Antal.Length - 5))
            {
                <button id="btnequls" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-container="body" data-original-title="some text">text here</button>
            }
            else
            {
                <button onclick="location.href = '/Account/RMA/@rma.Fakturnummer?Varenummer=@rma.Varenummer&Ordreno=@rma.Ordrenummer';" type="button" id="btnflere" class="btn">text </button>
            }
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

And then, when I tried do samething in my JavaScript, I can see `Tooltip` in `if` is not working and `href` inside button in `else` is not working too. Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction! Thanks in advance :)

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    let skip = 0;
    function SearchRMA(append, searching) {
        var amount = 10;
        skip += amount;
        var LikeOrderNummer = $("#SearchBox").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            url: "/Account/RMAHistorik",
            data: {
                LikeOrderNummer: LikeOrderNummer,
                From: CurrentPage * amount,
                Amount: amount,
                SearchRMA: true,
                Searching: searching,
                Skip: skip

            },
            success: function (result) {
                if ($.trim(result)) {

                    var ResultString = "";

                    $.each(result, function (i, e) {
                        ResultString +=
                            '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + dateFormat(new Date(parseInt((e.RMASendDato).match(/\d+/)[0]))) + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + '<a target="_blank" title="@Html.Raw(MitEdData.Resources.IndexTexts.Vis_sag)" href ="RMADetails?id=' + e.Id + '">' + "Sag nr:." + "&nbsp" + e.Id + '</a></td>' +
                            '<td>' + e.Ordrenummer + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + e.Fakturnummer + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + e.AntalRMA + ' @Html.Raw(MitEdData.Resources.IndexTexts.stk)' + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + e.Antal +  '</td>' +
                            '<td>'; // <-- here is my problem
                        if (e.AntalRMA == e.Antal) {
                            ResultString += '<button id="btnequls" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-container="body" data-original-title="Du har brugt alt dit antal RMA til denne sag">Opret flere sager</button>'
                        }
                        else {
                            ResultString += '<button onclick="location.href = RMA/' + e.Fakturnummer + '?Varenummer=' + e.Varenummer + '&Ordreno=' + e.Ordrenummer + '" type="button" id="btnflere" class="btn">Opret flere sager </button>'
                        } // <-- here is my problem too

                        ResultString += '</td>' +
                           '<td>' + e.Varenummer + '</td>' +
                            '<td>';

                        if (e.Status == "Sag i afventning") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:#f3bb45;" class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
                                e.Status;
                        }
                        else if (e.Status == "Sag oprettet") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:#34c834;" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
                             e.Status;
                        }
                        else if (e.Status == "Under behandling") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:rgba(220,77,70,1); font-size: 18px;" class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria- hidden="true"></i>' +
                            e.Status;
                        }
                        else if (e.Status == "Afventer vare") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:#34c834; font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-clock-o" aria- hidden="true"></i>' +
                            e.Status;
                        }
                        else if (e.Status == "Returpakkelabel fremsendt") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:#34c834; font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-exchange" aria- hidden="true"></i>' +
                            e.Status;
                        }
                        else if (e.Status == "Modtaget vare") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:#34c834; font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-archive" aria- hidden="true"></i>' +
                            e.Status;
                        }
                        else if (e.Status == "Afventer tilbagemelding fra kunde") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:#34c834; font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-clock-o" aria- hidden="true"></i>' +
                            e.Status;
                        }
                        else if (e.Status == "Sendt til værksted") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:#34c834; font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-truck" aria- hidden="true"></i>' +
                            e.Status;
                        }
                        else if (e.Status == "Afsluttet (vare returneret)") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:#34c834; font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-check" aria- hidden="true"></i>' +
                            e.Status;
                        }
                        else if (e.Status == "Afsluttet (vare krediteret)") {
                            ResultString += '<i style="color:#34c834; font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-check" aria- hidden="true"></i>' +
                            e.Status;
                        }

                        ResultString += '</td>' + '</tr>'
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#notfound").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> @Html.Raw(MitEdData.Resources.IndexTexts.Ingen_match_fundet______)</div>");
                }

                if (append) {
                    $("#ResultRMA").append(ResultString);
                }
                else {
                    $("#ResultRMA").html(ResultString);
                    $("#BackList").show();
                    $("#Next").hide();
                }

                //Back Button disbaled
                if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

                    history.pushState("nohb", null, "");
                    $(window).on("popstate", function (event) {
                        if (!event.originalEvent.state) {
                            history.pushState("nohb", null, "");
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                }

                function dateFormat(d) {
                    console.log(d);
                    return (d.getDate() + "").padStart(2, "0")
                        + "-" + ((d.getMonth() + 1) + "").padStart(2, "0")
                        + "-" + d.getFullYear();
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Tooltip JS :

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"], [rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: What do you think this line `'<td>';` is supposed to do on itself in your js? And do you really believe that ending your script with `+` is valid? Additionally, what is `e`? Last but not least, you do not seem to *actually* do anything with `ResultString`.

Comment: @Rafalon i dont post the whole code , i just updated my question :)

Comment: What is the value of `result`?

Comment: @Karan just updated my question :)

Comment: You still are not doing anything with `ResultString`.

Comment: @Rafalon alright, would you point me in right direction or just give me example with the code i posted :)

Comment: You should append `ResultString` object to your html and then add `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"], [rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();` this line at end of the `success` function.

Comment: have debug your JS? what result string returns?

Comment: What Karan and Vishal Khatal wrote. However, note that if you formatted you javascript correctly, you'd see that your opening brackets (`(` and `{`) do not match your closing ones (`)` and `}`)

Comment: @Rafalon as i said i post that line cause me problem and all you guys said i had in my script , however i mark with * of dat line which is cause me problem

Comment: How do you know your problem is at this specific line? Then what exactly ***is*** your problem?

Comment: Also why do you have so many conditions just to add `<i></i>` with *no text* in it? (and even if they where, maybe a [`switch`-`case`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_switch.asp) would fit better)

Comment: @Rafalon i just found out where was my problem and solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to append Resultstring to Table.for eg.

```
$("#TableName").append(Resultstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part

```
ResultString += '</td>' +

              '</tr>'
```

with this

```
ResultString += '</td>' +

              '</tr>';

$("#TableId tbody").append(Resultstring); //append your ResultString into the table
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"], [rel="tooltip"]').tooltip(); //initialize again the tooltip for the button
```

Comment: thanks for tooltip , i was forgot it to initialize again :)